# Error while creating an Hive Table on top of an Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am trying to create a Hive table on top of HBase, but getting error each time. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_trades(key string, value string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val") TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "trades");

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.io.IOException: Attempt to start meta tracker failed.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker.start(CatalogTracker.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getCatalogTracker(HBaseAdmin.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:269)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:476)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.createTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:598)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3697)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1485)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1091)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:931)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:921)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:684)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:623)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/meta-region-server
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker.start(CatalogTracker.java:195)
        ... 33 more
)
```

Comment: I have exactly same problem. How did you solve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Hive where to find the zookeepers quorum which would elect the HBase master

Change `zk1.mymachine.com,zk2.mymachine.com` with the name of your corresponding zookeepers' hosts.

```
$HIVE_SRC/build/dist/bin/hive -hiveconf hbase.zookeeper.quorum=zk1.mymachine.com,zk2.mymachine.com
```

Comment: @IbrarAhmed note that if you restart the service you will need to re-set it. Otherwise, change the value in hiveconf and make sure to restart the service afterwards for it to take effect.